# How can I see the type of a property in the Object Inspector?

Tags: delphi

In the form designer, I sometimes need to see the **type** of a property, so I know what kind of input it expects.  Unfortunately the Object Inspector doesn't seem to show it.

---

**Example:**

[image: Near-perfect circle]

This component clearly wants me to link a "Grid", but I have no idea what type of grid I need. TDbGrid? TDrawGrid? TColorGrid? TGridPanel?

Of course I can see this by looking into the source of the component, but does anyone know a faster way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any way to get at this from the Object Inspector.  You can always go into the code somewhere and type `JvGridFilter1.Grid` and press CTRL-SPACE and see what comes up, but that's pretty much the same as looking into the code.  I don't think there's any easier way to do it.

Try submitting that to QC as a feature request.

Comment: Bummer. That's what I was afraid of. 
Did the borland/codegear just never think of it, or would there be a good technical reason?

Comment: From what I've read, the Object Inspector uses RTTI to inspect the objects, and the type information is available there.  So probably they just never thought of it.

Comment: Yep, I agree -- that would be a good thing to add.  Put it into the VCL/RTL section of http://delphi.uservoice.com

Comment: even cooler: when a property like this is empty (meaning no applicable component on the form), automatically filter the component palette for components of the appropriate type - what a time-saver!